# Remove duplicates from sorted array and return length - Must mutate the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

**DISCLAIMER**

> I am well aware of the duplicate questions, however this one is asking to remove duplicates without making a new array and wants us to mutate the original array.

**INSTRUCTIONS**

> Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that each element appear only once and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

**EXAMPLE**

Given `nums = [1,1,2]`,

Your function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of `nums` being 1 and 2 respectively.

It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length.

**ATTEMPT**

```js
const removeDuplicates = function(nums) {

   for(let i of nums){
     if(nums[i] === nums[i]){
        nums.splice(i, 1)
     }
   }
   return nums.length;
};

console.log(removeDuplicates([1, 1, 2]));
console.log(removeDuplicates([1, 2]));

// [1, 1, 2] => [1, 2] (Correct)
// [1, 2]    => [1]    (Incorrect - should be [1, 2])
```

Am I mutating the array correctly with splice and what do I need to do to correct the 2nd argument?

Also, in leetcode, when I run the first argument, it says it's correct and returns the array of the leftover elements, but the instructions were asking for the length of the new array. Not sure if I'm missing something but why is it not returning the length?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzUSw.jpg

Comment: `splice` is supposed to take the index of the value you want to remove, not the value itself. Try changing your array to `[3, 3, 2]` and see what happens.

Comment: @HereticMonkey gives me `2`

Comment: `if(nums[i] === nums[i])` is always true.

Comment: @Kosh so change it to `nums[i + 1]`?

Comment: Yes. change to `i+1`

Comment: @Kosh ok tried that and now my first console log answer is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
const removeDuplicates = function(nums) {

   for(let i = 0; i < nums.length;){
     if(nums[i] === nums[++i]){
        nums.splice(i, 1)
     }
   }
   return nums.length;
};

console.log(removeDuplicates([1, 1, 2]));
console.log(removeDuplicates([1, 2]));
```

Comment: what does `++i` mean?

Comment: @and1, increment

Comment: What's the difference between this  `++i` and `i++`?

Comment: @and1, `++i` increments i than use it, `i++` first use i than increments it.

Comment: @and1 increment "then' use

Answer (score 2):

```js
let nums = [1,1,2];
nums = [...new Set(nums)].length;
console.log(nums);
nums = [1,1,2];
nums = nums.filter(function(item, pos, self) {
  return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
console.log(nums)
```

Comment: appreciate it, but isn't this not mutating the original array?

Comment: You could write something like this `nums = [...new Set(nums)].length;`

Comment: They said `Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.`

Answer (score 2):

For each element of the array you need to iterate through all remaining elements of that array, to check for all duplicates. Not sure if this is more performant then making a copy.

```js
const removeDuplicates = function (nums) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < nums.length) {
        let j = i + 1;
        while (j < nums.length) {
            if (nums[i] === nums[j]) {
                nums.splice(j, 1);
            }
            else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return nums.length;
};
console.log(removeDuplicates([1, 1, 2]));
console.log(removeDuplicates([1, 2]));
console.log(removeDuplicates([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]));

// [1, 1, 2] => [1, 2] (Correct)
// [1, 2]    => [1]    (Incorrect - should be [1, 2])
// [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

The hint is in the line: `It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length.`

Whoever is asking you this wants you to move through the array keeping track of 2 pointers: 1) The end of the output array and 2) the current index in the input array.

If you do this, and copy the input to the output pointer only when they're different, you will end up with the correct output, the correct length (from the output pointer) and a little bit of garbage at the end of the array.

```
const unique = (arr) => {
  let output = 0;
  for (let input = 0; input < arr.length; input++) {
    if (arr[output] !== arr[input]) {
      output++;
      arr[output] = arr[input];
    }
  }
  return output + 1;
}

const arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 11];
const length = unique(arr);
console.log(arr, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solution will pass more test cases (at least in my personal testing)

```
  const removeDups = (nums) => {
  
  // since mutating arrays I like to start at the end of the array so when the index is removed it doesn't impact the loop
  let i = nums.length - 1;

  while(i > 0){
    // --i decrements then evaluates (i.e 5 === 4), i-- decriments after the evaluation (i.e 5 === 5 then decrements the last 5 to 4)
    if(nums[i] === nums[--i]){  
      // remove the current index (i=current index, 1=number of indexes to remove including itself)
      nums.splice(i,1);  
    }
  }

  console.log(nums);
  return nums.length;

};

// Test Cases 
console.log(removeDups([1,1,2]));   // 2
console.log(removeDups([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4])); // 5
console.log(removeDups([0,0,0,2,3,3,4,4,5,5])); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the solution provided by Kosh above, but it failed  for bigger array [0,0,1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]. So ended up writing my own. Seems to work for all tests.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
    const tempNum = nums[i];
    var j;
    var tempIndex = [];
    for (j = i+1; j <= nums.length; j++) {
      if (tempNum === nums[j]) {
        tempIndex.push(j)
      }
    }
    nums.splice(tempIndex[0], tempIndex.length)
  }
  return (nums.length);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
   let i = nums.length - 1;

  while(i > 0){
   
    if(nums[i] === nums[--i]){  
      
      nums.splice(i,1);  
    }
  }

  return nums.length;

};
```